# Does NTP compromise anonymity?

Tags: anonymity, ntp

I read today for the first time about the NTP protocol, and realized I have a NTP daemon running on my system, with a socket syncing to some (assumed randomly selected) server.

Does this at all have the risk of compromising my anonymity online. If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: what kind of anonymity? Who do you want to stay anonymous from?

Comment: Malice figures out you use ntp1.lougle.com as your time server, so roots it then sends back slightly wrong times for your computer only and then your computer uses that time in TOR connections...hm

Comment: I am asking in general terms, so maybe the "who" isn't so relevant. As to kind, coming across NTP made me instinctively think about the topics DNS leakage and identification by correlation. Also in general terms, I guess.

Comment: I'd recommend using OpenNTPD as it does a cross-check against www.google.com's TLS timestamp, so it's harder to spoof

Comment: Yes, it is possible to skew system time in broadcast mode (CVE-2015-7973)